# JPA Unary Operators

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I want to know if it is possible to set a boolean value in JPA with Unary Operator. 
I mean something like this

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Computer com set com.enabled=!com.enabled where com.id = ?1")
```

The enabled field is mapped like this in the POJO

```
private Boolean enabled;

public Boolean getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}
```

in the DB it is stored as `boolean(1)`

this is the result

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: expecting '=', found 'c' [update com.nicinc.Computer com set com.enabled=!com.enabled where com.id = ?1]
```

and here the JPA properties

## Spring Data JPA properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: do you get any errors? or its simply not working for you?

Comment: can you add the Computer mapping class? especially that boolean field.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different databases have different support for handling of boolean expressions, so there is little room for JPA to provide a generalized approach, thus you have to be explicit:

```
update Computer
set enabled = case when enabled = true then false else true end
where id = ?1
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are using `tinyint` on the MySQL side for that column and persistence provider cannot distinguish `0` and `1` as being `false` or `true`.

If you are using `JPA 2.1` then i would suggest creating a global converter for boolean conversion:

```
@Converter(autoApply=true)
public class GlobalBooleanConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, Integer>{
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Boolean value) {
        if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(value)) {
            return Integer.valueOf(1);
        } else {
            return Integer.valueOf(0);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(String value) {
        return Integer.valueOf(1).equals(value);
    }
}
```

A bit out of the box alternative would be to change the POJO field to Integer and change the query to following:

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Computer com set com.enabled=((-com.enabled)+1) where com.id = ?1")
```

Comment: with the second solution I don't the error when I start the application but it does not update the field properly

Comment: can you give an example?